# Specific for-loop for a simple sort algorithm

Tags: c

this is a simple code for sorting a table from max to min. I am confused because my professor used `for(i=0; i<10-1; i++)` and I saw that it works fine with `for(i=0; i<10; i++)`. Can please someone tell me the difference?
Thanks for your time, appreciate your help.

```
int a[10];
int i, j, t;

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}


for(i=0; i<10-1; i++)   
{
    for(j=i+1; j<10; j++)
    {
        if (a[i]>a[j])
        {
            t=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=t;
        }
    }
}

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Usually, these kind of algorithms do not stop at the last one, but an element before. In fact, at that point, the nth-1 element is already sorted with respect of the nth one. So, both works, but the "-1" is more efficient because you skip a useless iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professor is correct, although your way does work too; it's just clumsier:

Given that the starting value of `j` is `i + 1`, in order to avoid a out of bounds access to the array `a` (the behaviour of which is *undefined*), you need to constrain `i` to be less than 9 and `i + 1` to be less than 10. Essentially your professor constrains the former, but you constrain the latter.

The *bubble sort* works this way as sortedness is established once the outer loop has processed the penultimate element.

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment:

Usually, these kind of algorithms do not stop at the last one, but an element before. In fact, at that point, the nth-1 element is already sorted with respect of the nth one. So, both works, but the "-1" is more efficient because you skip a useless iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `for(i=0; i<10; i++)` you get one additional iteration of the external loop, in wich `i` is equal `9`. But then in the internal loop `j` is equal `10` at once, condition `j < 10` isn't met, and the internal loop terminates without executing its body.

Comment: Have an upvote. You got the answer correct first time (unlike me).